# htaccess 404 redirect with strings?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

On `domain.com` is hosted a blog with permalinks set up as `domain.com/article and domain.com/category`.

Now, the blog is moved to `domain.com/blog` and some other content is put directly on domain.com : `file2.php` , `filex.php`

Now, how can you make a redirect when users enters on `domain.com/articlex` to be redirected to `domain.com/blog/articlex` ?

To don't interfere with the new content, i'm thinking to redirect 301 the 404 page response.

I'm trying in .htaccess with ErrorDocument 404 `404.php`, and from there to make a 301 redirect but there is no `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` available.

Also, with `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} = 404` to redirect with query strings I had no success.

Comment: i managed to make it work with default 404.shtml and the redirect is made using location,window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to point not found pages to page where you will make redirects

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* redirect.php [L]
```

And in redirect.php write code you planned for 404.php, you will have `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` available there, also you need to handle not found pages in redirect.php file